# Why does R sometimes think ASCII characters are non-ASCII?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to identify elements in a dataframe that contain non-ASCII characters. For example, in the dataframe below I would want all rows in the `unicode_only` column and the last two rows in the `mixed` column.

```
example_dataset <- tribble(
  ~ascii_only, ~unicode_only, ~mixed,
  "a",         "表",          "c",
  "b",         "外",          "表",
  "c",         "字",          "外",
)
```

When I try filtering elements using the regular expression `"[^[:ascii]]"`, however, some ASCII-only elements are included.

```
example_dataset %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(everything(), -row_number),
               names_to = "variable") %>%
  select(variable, row_number, value) %>%
  arrange(variable, row_number) %>%
  filter(str_detect(value, "[^[:ascii]]"))
```

| variable | row_number | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ascii_only | 2 | b |
| mixed | 2 | 表 |
| mixed | 3 | 外 |
| unicode_only | 1 | 表 |
| unicode_only | 2 | 外 |
| unicode_only | 3 | 字 |

Why would `"[^[:ascii]]"` match `b`?

Comment: You're missing a colon in the pattern `[:ascii:]` so it's currently matching against a literal `a` or `c`

Comment: Thanks Brian--that fixed it. I'm not sure how I failed to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is `[:ascii:]` and not `[:ascii]`.